# How come HTML5 video plays inconsistently in Firefox 11?

Tags: html, firefox, webm

I have the following HTML5 video code on my homepage and it acts strange in Firefox 11.

```
<video width="900" height="508" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
    <source type="video/webm" src="http://www.mysite.com/MovieClip.webm"></source>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.mysite.com/MovieClip.mp4"></source>
</video>
```

When the homepage on my site loads, I see in the place of the video the following error message:
**"No video with supported format and MIME type found."**

However, when I open up the media path **"http://www.mysite.com/MovieClip.webm"** directly, in a new tab, it loads the media just fine (using the internal Firefox HTML5 video player)!

Then, right afterwards when I go back to my homepage and refresh the page, it now loads the video just fine! Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Be certain that your web server is configured to deliver WebM video as MIME type "video/webm". You can quickly and manually check if this is the case by telnetting to your web server and issuing a HEAD request:

```
telnet www.mysite.com 80
```

[after connection...]

```
HEAD /MovieClip.webm HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mysite.com
```

And finish the request with 2 carriage returns. The HTTP response header should contain a "Content-Type:" line. If it doesn't say "video/webm", Firefox won't accept your WebM file.

Comment: It does show it as video/webm. I also noticed that in the Firefox Net tab, the first time (when it has trouble loading it), it shows up as Content-Type: application/octet-stream, and then I also see another strange line called Working-Content-Type: video/webm. But once I open the video in another tab and then go back to the site and refresh it, it then works and shows the Content-Type as video/webm as expected. Strange!

Comment: I'd suggest flushing out your browser caches, shutting down the browser and trying again (though I suspect you have already tried this once or twice).

Comment: What happens when you eliminate the MP4 source from the HTML text? I wonder if Firefox is getting confused by that. Also, what version of Firefox on which platform?

Comment: Also, what web server is delivering this? And are you certain that the "Working-Content-Type:" header is delivered over the wire? Your comment about the Firefox Net tab (I'm not familiar with that facility) makes it sound like maybe Firefox injected that header.

Comment: I tried eliminating the mp4 source and that didn't work. The Working-Content-Type (which I'm not even sure what it is) only gets shown whenever it is unable to load the video. Then, after I successfully open up the video source directly in the FF browser and then go back to the webpage and refresh it, it then no longer shows a Working-Content-Type and only shows the desired Content-Type: video/webm and the video loads just fine. The web server is IIS and the Net tab, by the way, is one of the Firebug tabs.

Comment: Thanks multimedia mike. Your content type thing helped me. I forced the server to serve the right thing by adding this: AddType application/x-shockwave-flash swf
AddType video/mp4 mp4
AddType video/ogg ogg
AddType video/webm webm
To a .htaccess file in the video directory.
The video (webm) directly called is working. But in the player i get "video loading stopped". Any idea?

Comment: Okay. Anyways. Restarting firefox helped me out.

Answer (score 2):

Regardng to Multimedia Mikes answer. If your server delivers the wrong mime type to the videos just put a htaccess file with following content into your videos directory:

```
AddType video/mp4 mp4
AddType video/ogg ogg
AddType video/webm webm
```

This worked out well.

If, please rate his answer ;)

Greetings
func0der

Comment: Can you post an url so i can check whether it works for me or other users?

Comment: Actually it is not on a publicly accessible URL yet. Also, a couple more clues. First of all, when I said Working Content Type, I meant Content-WorkType. Also, I noticed the status code returned on the MovieClip.webm to be a 206 Partial Content. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, when I point my FF browser to that specific file itself, it plays in the browser just fine.

Comment: No i mean on the site itself. Does it play in the videoplayer? Without u visiting: http://www.func0der.de/html5videotest/videos/video1.webm

Comment: Does my site work for you?
Could you please provide an example link or something?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure this will solve your problem, but we also have noticed erratic behavior with .webm movies in Firefox 11 (only on Windows): The video element's playhead automatically jumps to the end of the movie, even if you open the file explicitly, i.e. without a surrounding HTML page. This of course renders all autoplay settings unusable.

Our solution was to change the order of the sources, so that Firefox would prefer .ogg files over .webm - there was no need to change anything else in the HTML code.